# Problems installing a VeriSign Certificate in the Certificate Store On Developer Machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, certificate, verisign

I have a Visual Studio 2010 VSTO Outlook Add In project that was originally created in Visual Studio 2008.  The VSTO dll project is signed with a VeriSign Certificate (Pfx file).  When the project was created under VS 2008, there were no issues in building it on a new developer machine.  Now, under VS 2010, we are getting the following build error:

> "Cannot import the following key file: Blah.pfx.  The key file may be
>   password protected. To corrrect this, try to import the certificate
>   again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with
>   the following key container name: VS_KEY_blahblahblahblah"

For some time I was able to use sn.exe -i to manually install the certificate into the Strong Name CSP, as the error suggests, and all was fine.  Now, I get the following cryptic  error message when I try to use sn.exe -i to install the certificate:

> "Failed to parse the PKCS#12 blob in blah.pfx -- An internal error
>   occurred"

Does anyone know what causes this failure, and how to fix it?  I've seen a couple of posts about setting permissions on the MachineKeys folder under Microsoft/Crypto/RSA, and I've tried that, but still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a Microsoft Premier Support incident for this problem, and it turned out that our Certificate had become corrupted.  The solution was to replace it with a new Certificate.